# How to comment the whole block of code that already contaning /* comments (Java)?

Tags: java

Let see this example in Java,

```
    public void methodY(){
        /* some explain ...... */
        int x=1;
    }
```

Ok, now I want to comment the whole methodY so I put methodY inside `/*` `*/` like this:

```
    /*
    public void methodY(){
        /* inside comment ...... */
        int x=1;
    } 
    */
However, the inside comment /* inside comment ...... */ prevent that to be happen.
```

In Java, do we have a way to comment the whole block of code that already containing /* comments?

Comment: If code is already inside multi line comment then compiler ignores all those statement inside /* some explain ...... */

Comment: just move the /* tag upwards

Comment: You can use // to comment all unused lines

Comment: what if we have so many /* ... */  & that cost me a lot odf time to remove

Comment: also when i want to reuse the code then the whole code got messed up

Comment: If you have a lot of comments you should try to write simpler code.

Comment: Why shouldn't you put comment inside method using "//"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment this using inline comment `//`.

Typically IDEs support <kbd>Ctrl-/</kbd> on selected block.

Comment: That keycomb does not work in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA, Norwegian key mapping).

Comment: @Tum - Press *Ctrl+/* again to undo it.

Comment: @turn : you have to select the exact number of lines which have been commented to undo it... falter there, then you will end up adding another set of comment (//) symbols..

Comment: excelent, thax you very much

Answer (score 1):

For example in Netbeans you can select all lines and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, this will comment in whole section (not sure if it recomments the `/* ... */` again) in `//` style.

I think there are similar options available in other IDE's.

I am not aware of Java itself processing 'double' comment blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the block of text(already containing comments) you want to comment and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. But this might override the comments already present, which needs to be taken care of.

Instead you can try inline comments, by either providing `//` at the beginning of each line or using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> key combination and press it again to undo it. But you need to know that if you comment each line using the inline comment, then you can avoid that scenario, but it would make your job of commenting a bit tedious if the block to be commented has a lot of lines.

The call to use either of the commenting styles is upto you and the needs.

Note: This works for Eclipse running on Windows.

Comment: That depends on the IDE.

Comment: @MrBackend - Added the note to mention that :)

Comment: if i do that then it remove the double comment & if i want to reuse the method then i have to find the line that i commented before & comment? this is dangerous as some comnet the line of code

Comment: @Tum - That happens when you do the block comment. But if you comment each line using the inline comment, then you can avoid that scenario, but that makes your job a bit tedious if the block to be commented has a lot of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Select the passage and give <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

P.S : In eclipse IDE

Answer (score 1):

ON eclipse select the block you want to comment and use:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

eclipse select the block you want to comment and use:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse IDE : you can use

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (to comment and uncomment both)

or you can use  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (to comment) and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (to uncomment)